# weblogic response requests time

Tags: weblogic

Please let me know whether it's possible to configure weblogic response requests time. As of new we have configuration on HTTPD, but due to performance issues on weblogic/java side we would like to have response time info from weblogic

Answer (score 1):

You can use weblogic's http logs to achieve this. Before, you just have to update your servers' configuration to setup access logs in extended format to have the time-taken information. Have a look to this product documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/web_server.htm#CNFGD204